# HTML Prefetch Resources

Tags: html, algorithm, cross-browser, httprequest, prefetch

This might be a silly question but I want to ask if prefetching resources like js scripts and images slows page load.

eg: If I have a page with a number of these links:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://example.com/images.png" />
```

Will downloading them be included in the page load time or is prefetching (which using idle browser time) not part of the page load time stats?

Does it truly happen in the background in idle time or is it just another part of the page load?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is browser dependent:

> Android browser, Firefox, and Firefox mobile start prefetch requests after window.onload, but Chrome and Opera start them immediately possibly stealing TCP connections from more important resources needed for the current page.

Starting with IE11, individual network requests are prioritized by type, generally in this order.

1. The root document of the webpage
2. CSS stylesheets
3. WOFF fonts
4. Script libraries
5. Images loaded using onload event handlers
6. Synchronous XMLHttpRequest (XHR) requests
7. Asynchronous script requests (such as indexedDB, Web Workers, File API, and others)
8. Asynchronous XHR requests
9. HTML5 audio and video
10. Microsoft ActiveX and other controls loaded using the object element
11. Deferred JavaScript (defer="true")

The context is also important:

> IE11 also prioritizes requests based on context of the request:

1. Requests made by the webpage in the foreground tab
2. Requests made by content loaded in iframe elements in the foreground tab
3. Requests made by webpages in background tabs
4. Requests for pre-rendered content

**References**

- [Prebrowsing](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/11/07/prebrowsing/)
- [IE11 Network Prioritization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn265036)
- [Getting to the Content You Want, Faster in IE11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/12/04/getting-to-the-content-you-want-faster-in-ie11.aspx)
- [Chromium: New JavaScript Techniques for Rapid Page Loads](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/03/new-javascript-techniques-for-rapid.html)
- [‎Chromium: The Trace Event Profiling Tool (about:tracing)‎](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool/trace-event-reading)
- [Chromium: Inter-Process Communication](https://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication)
- [MDN: HTML5 Parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_Parser)
- [MDN: Controlling DNS Prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Controlling_DNS_prefetching)
- [MDN: Tips for authoring fast-loading HTML pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Tips_for_authoring_fast-loading_HTML_pages)